# dplyr::select() with some variables that may not exist in the data frame?

Tags: r, select, dplyr, nse, tidyselect

I have a helper function (say `foo()`) that will be run on various data frames that may or may not contain specified variables.  Suppose I have

```
library(dplyr)
d1 <- data_frame(taxon=1,model=2,z=3)
d2 <- data_frame(taxon=2,pss=4,z=3)
```

The variables I want to select are

```
vars <- intersect(names(data),c("taxon","model","z"))
```

that is, I'd like `foo(d1)` to return the `taxon`, `model`, and `z` columns, while `foo(d2)` returns just `taxon` and `z`.

If `foo` contains `select(data,c(taxon,model,z))` then `foo(d2)` fails (because `d2` doesn't contain `model`). If I use `select(data,-pss)` then `foo(d1)` fails similarly.

I know how to do this if I retreat from the tidyverse (just return `data[vars]`), but I'm wondering if there's a handy way to do this either (1) with a `select()` helper of some sort (`tidyselect::select_helpers`) or (2) with tidyeval (which I **still** haven't found time to get my head around!)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Another option is `select_if`:

```
d2 %>% select_if(names(.) %in% c('taxon', 'model', 'z'))

# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#   taxon     z
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     2     3
```

---

`select_if` is superseded. Use `any_of` instead:

```
d2 %>% select(any_of(c('taxon', 'model', 'z')))
# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#   taxon     z
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     2     3
```

type `?dplyr::select` in R and you will find this:

> These helpers select variables from a character vector:
>
> all_of(): Matches variable names in a character vector. All names must
> be present, otherwise an out-of-bounds error is thrown.
>
> any_of(): Same as all_of(), except that no error is thrown for names
> that don't exist.

Comment: all answers are good, but this one is compact and readable and doesn't throw any warnings. (@G.Grothendieck's is closest to the method I gave).

Comment: or: `d2 %>% select(which(names(.) %in% c('taxon', 'model', 'z')))`

Comment: always good to have alternatives, but `select_if(...)` seems better than `select(which(...))`

Comment: `select_if (names(.)...` is very, very slow for larger data.frames.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `one_of()`, which gives a warning when the column is absent but otherwise selects the correct columns:

```
d1 %>%
    select(one_of(c("taxon", "model", "z")))
d2 %>%
    select(one_of(c("taxon", "model", "z")))
```

Comment: `one_of()` is retired in favor of `any_of()` (applicable here) or `all_of()` (which would error if a variable is not present).

Answer (score 6):

Using the builtin `anscombe` data frame for the example noting that `z` is not a column in `anscombe` :

```
anscombe %>% select(intersect(names(.), c("x1", "y1", "z")))
```

giving:

```
   x1    y1
1  10  8.04
2   8  6.95
3  13  7.58
4   9  8.81
5  11  8.33
6  14  9.96
7   6  7.24
8   4  4.26
9  12 10.84
10  7  4.82
11  5  5.68
```